# How to fetch data in MongoDB as Catgepory > Sub Catgeory > Product using nodejs

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have 3 different models which relates each other i want to join them by Id. the response which i want is given below

Please find below sample data:

I want this type of json in response

```
      "categoryData": [
    {
    "_id": "5f227a756c42fe34e883be3c",
    "categoryName": "Cake",
    "categoryDescription": "Cake",
    "IsActive": true,
    "EnteredBy": null,
    "WhenEntered": "2020-07-30T07:44:52.409Z",
    "ModifiedBy": null,
    "WhenModified": null,
    "__v": 0,
    "subcategorydata": [
    {
    "_id": "5f23c85d3926134528cb8208",
    "categoryId": "5f227a756c42fe34e883be3c",
    "subcategoryName": "SugerFree Cake",
    "subcategoryDescription": "SugerFree Cake",
    "IsActive": true,
    "EnteredBy": null,
    "WhenEntered": "2020-07-31T07:29:33.829Z",
    "ModifiedBy": null,
    "WhenModified": null,
    "__v": 0,
    "ProductData": [
    {
    "_id": "5f23c83e3926134528cb8207",
    "ProductName": "Eggless Cake",
    "ProductDescription": "Eggless Cake",
    "IsActive": true,
    "EnteredBy": null,
    "WhenEntered": "2020-07-31T07:29:02.877Z",
    "ModifiedBy": null,
    "WhenModified": null,
    "__v": 0
    },
    {
    "_id": "5f23c83e3926134528cb8207",
    "ProductName": "Eggless Cake",
    "ProductDescription": "Eggless Cake",
    "IsActive": true,
    "EnteredBy": null,
    "WhenEntered": "2020-07-31T07:29:02.877Z",
    "ModifiedBy": null,
    "WhenModified": null,
    "__v": 0
    },
    }}
```

Please help me in this..Thank you.

Comment: Hey Manish.. Are you saying that you have three different collections and you which to fetch all this data in one single query from different collections matched to their respective ids ??

Answer (score 0):

Refer [MONGO AGGREGATION LOOKUP](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)

```
db.category.aggregate([
   {
     $lookup:
       {
         from: "subcategory",
         localField: "_id",
         foreignField: "categoryId",
         as: "subcategory_items"
       }
  }
])
```

For Further Reference : [MULTIPLE COLLECTION JOIN QUERY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40789057/mongodb-join-multiple-collections)